# How to download image inline instead of `save image as` using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to download image in the same window instead of asking the end user to use `save-image-as` or `Ctrl+S` in `react.js`.

The following function is written in the Stateful `Class`.

```
forceDownload(event){
    alert(event.target.getAttribute('value'));
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'Download.jpg';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.href = event.target.getAttribute('value');
    link.click();
}
```

The following code is written in `render` part

```
<a value={imageUrl} onClick={this.forceDownload}>Download</a>
```

The solution works fine only when the `alert` throws `null` instead of the actual `imageUrl`. Is there anything missed out?

Comment: your code should work perfectly.. even  i have written the same thing
https://github.com/shivasai09/resume/blob/c187790acd58c7be7ee4f350ccf988cab70b52ab/client/src/App.js#L156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `blob` and convert it into downloadable link.

```
forceDownload(event){
    const data = event.target.getAttribute('value');
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'quote.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```